# How to reorder the columns of a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

How can I re-order the columns of a CSV file using Python? These are the first rows of a CSV file I need to change:

```
03;30269714;Ramiro Alberto;Nederz;active;pgc_gral
03;36185520;Andrea;Espare;active;pgc_gral
03;24884344;Maria Roxana;Nietto;active;pgc_gral
03;27461021;Veronica Andrea;Lantier;active;pgc_gral
71;24489743;Diego;Moneta;active;pgc_gral
```

This is the desired output:

```
30269714;pgc_gral; Ramiro Alberto;Nederz
36185520;pgc_gral; Andrea;Espare
24884344;pgc_gral;Maria Roxana;Nietto
27461021;pgc_gral;Veronica Andrea;Lantier
24489743;pgc_gral;Diego;Moneta
```

Column 2 is now column 1, column 6 is column 2, columns 3 and 4 should stay the same and column 5 should be discarded.

Comment: Did you try to solve it already? post some code that we can review and help guide you

Comment: Take a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html, csv isn't sophisticated enough to do translations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('yourfile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print(";".join([row[1], row[5], row[2], row[3]]))
```

Comment: Hello.. I have a similar need to write  to a csv file as well. So I used "," as  a separator :
with open('abc.csv', 'r', newline='',encoding='utf-8') as f1, open('xyz.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding='utf-8') as _finalf:
    reader = csv.reader(finalf, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(_finalf,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        row=",".join([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[5], row[3],row[4]])
        print(row)
But each and every  characters in each field is showing separately:
N A M E , A G E, H E I G H T
J O H N , 1 2 3, S M A L L

Can you please suggest?

Comment: The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996230/change-order-of-columns-in-csv-python worked for me to reorder csv columns.