# change order of columns in csv (python)

Tags: python, csv

I made a script, which reads a given input-file (**csv**), manipulates the data somehow and writes an output-file (**csv**).

In my case, my given input-file looks like this:

```
| sku | article_name |
| 1   | MyArticle    |
```

For my output-file, I need to re-arrange these columns (there are plenty more, but I think i might be able to solve it, when someone shows me the way)

My output-file should look like this:

```
| article_name | another_column | sku |
| MyArticle    |                | 1   |
```

Note, that here is a new column, that isn't in the source csv-file, but it has to be printed anyway (the order is important as well)

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin_1 -*-

import csv
import argparse
import sys


header_mappings = {'attr_artikel_bezeichnung1': 'ARTICLE LABEL',
                   'sku': 'ARTICLE NUMBER',
                   'Article label locale': 'Article label locale',
                   'attr_purchaseprice': 'EK-Preis',
                   'attr_salesPrice': 'EuroNettoPreis',
                   'attr_salesunit': 'Einheit',
                   'attr_salesvatcode': 'MwSt.-Satz',
                   'attr_suppliercode': 'Lieferantennummer',
                   'attr_suppliersitemcode': 'Artikelnummer Lieferant',
                   'attr_isbatchitem': 'SNWarenausgang'}

row_mapping = {'Einheit': {'pc': 'St.'},
               'MwSt.-Satz': {'3': '19'}}


def remap_header(header):
    for h_map in header_mappings:
        if h_map in header:
            yield header_mappings.get(h_map), header.get(h_map)


def map_header(header):
    for elem in header:
        yield elem, header.index(elem)


def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as incsv:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(incsv, delimiter=';')
        for r in csv_reader:
            yield r


def add_header(header, fields=()):
    for f in fields:
        header.append(f)

    return header


def duplicate(csv_row, header_name, fields):
    csv_row[new_csv_header.index(fields)] = csv_row[new_csv_header.index(header_name)]
    return csv_row


def do_new_row(csv_row):
    for header_name in new_csv_header:
        for r_map in row_mapping:
            row_content = csv_row[mapped_header.get(r_map)]
            if row_content in row_mapping.get(r_map):
                csv_row[mapped_header.get(r_map)] = row_mapping.get(r_map).get(row_content)
        try:
            yield csv_row[mapped_header.get(header_name)]
        except TypeError:
            continue


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--infile', metavar='CSV')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--outfile', metavar='CSV')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    arguments = vars(args)
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
        parser.print_usage()
        sys.exit(0)

    # print arguments
    # parse_csv(**arguments)
    """
    """
    csv_reader_iter = read_csv(arguments.get('infile'))

    # neuer csv header
    new_csv_header = list()
    csv_header = next(csv_reader_iter)
    for h in csv_header:
        if h in header_mappings:
            new_csv_header.append(header_mappings.get(h))

    # print new_csv_header
    new_csv_header = add_header(new_csv_header, ('Article label locale', 'Nummer'))
    mapped_header = dict(remap_header(dict(map_header(csv_header))))
    # print mapped_header

    with open(arguments.get('outfile'), 'wb') as outcsv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=';')
        csv_writer.writerow(new_csv_header)
        for row in csv_reader_iter:
            row = list(do_new_row(row))
            delta = len(new_csv_header) - len(row)
            if delta > 0:
                row = row + (delta * [''])

            # duplicate(row, 'SNWarenausgang', 'SNWareneingang')
            # duplicate(row, 'SNWarenausgang', 'SNWareneingang')
            csv_writer.writerow(row)


    print "Done."
    """
    print new_csv_header
    for row in csv_reader_iter:
        row = list(do_new_row(row))
        delta = len(new_csv_header) - len(row)
        if delta > 0:
            row = row + (delta * [''])

        duplicate(row, 'Herstellernummer', 'Nummer')
        duplicate(row, 'SNWarenausgang', 'SNWareneingang')
        print row
    """
```

Right now, even though it says "ARTICLE LABEL" first, the sku is printed first. My guess: This is due the order of the csv-file, since sku is the first field there... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As riotburn already suggested, you can use a [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and its `fieldnames` argument to adjust the order of columns in the new file.

Reordering a file could look like this:

```
def read_csv (filename):
    with open(filename) as incsv:
       reader = csv.DictReader(incsv, delimiter=';')
       for r in reader:
           yield r

columns = ['article_name', 'another_column', 'sku']

with open('newfile.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, columns, delimiter=';')
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in read_csv('oldfile.csv'):
        # add a property
        row['another_column'] = 'foo'

        # write row (using the order specified in columns)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `DictWriter` from the `csv` lib you can specify the order of the columns.  Use `DictReader` to read in rows from your file as dicts.  Then you just explicitly specify the order of the keys when you create your `DictWriter`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: Would I have to adjust the "do_new_row"-function? I'm sorry, I'm just used to PHP =(

Comment: Can you, if possible, show me an example on my code? Where should this DictWriter be?

Comment: You want to replace `csv.reader` with `csv.DictReader` and `csv.writer` with `csv.DictWriter`.  The link I provided has examples of using these.  You would have to modify your code because you would now be working with `dicts` instead of `lists`.

Comment: I tried to replace csv.reader with your solution, but that ended up in having errors (as you already told me, since I'm using dicts instead of lists. May i ask for further help?