# Need to exchange two sets of tabular data in a TXT file using Python

Tags: python

I have a set of coordinate data (saved in a txt file), like this:

```
Number  N coordinates   E coordinates   Height  Code
1       5111945.980     444258.900      131.300 C
2       5265566.655     443665.554      110.311 BR  
...
```

It goes on for several dozen rows like that.
What I need done is to switch places of N coordinates with the ones on E coordinates (the header title also, of course) while everything else remains the same. For example, this would be the desired outcome in an output txt file:

```
Number  E coordinates   N coordinates   Height  Code
1       444258.900      5111945.980     131.300 C
2       443665.554      5265566.655     110.311 BR
```

For now, I only have the bit for printing out the table data as it shows in txt:

```
# open the source file
myfile = open("sometext.txt", "r")

# print out the data, to check if output working
for line in myfile:
    print(line)
```

The data is tab spaced, as far as I can see.

I would like to solve this without external libraries, only default Python and its standard library.

Comment: Is the data tab-delimited or fixed-width columns like in your example? It should be very easy to find solutions for both problems. Please search before asking.

Comment: do you have to have a txt file or are you open to other formats as well? and does the columns are always in tab space or some number of spaces or?

Comment: Are there any limitations on the way this will be achieved? for example libraries you don't want to use

Comment: @tripleee Tried searching for it, been doing it for an hour or so already and I'm stuck...

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @tripleee Why do you care? the OP has admitted to search for hours, trust him, I am sure he's not going to be a millionaire from this question, so helping him isn't a crime or something it be jealous about. I am an SJW so don't mind me if I offended you.

Comment: Because if they show us what they searched for we can suggest better search terms. A complication is that 90% of the search hits are for Pandas.

Comment: @tripleee How come you mention pandas after reading his comment about "vanilla python only"

Comment: Maybe read the comment again? I mention that it complicates matters that it's easier to find a Pandas solution and thus harder to find one which doesn't use Pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change order of columns in csv (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996230/change-order-of-columns-in-csv-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution with no third-party libraries

```py
rows_to_be_switched = ['Number', 'Code']

def flip(row_to_flip, ind1, ind2):
    tmp = row_to_flip[ind1]
    row_to_flip[ind1] = row_to_flip[ind2]
    row_to_flip[ind2] = tmp
    return row_to_flip


with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
    data_rows = [row.rstrip('\n') for row in file1.readlines()]
    titles_indices = [data_rows[0].split('\t').index(title) for title in rows_to_be_switched]

    for row in data_rows:
        file2.write('\t'.join(flip(row.split('\t'), *titles_indices) + ['\n']))
```

---

Explanation:

- The `rows_to_be_switched` is a list of two titles that we flip between.
- The `flip` functions flips the indices of the items in a list and returns the new list
- `titles_indices = [data_rows[0].split('\t').index(title) for title in rows_to_be_switched]` Detects the indices of the titles, and knows where to flip each two items in a row.
- We then write each row by joining the items with a tab, as it was the delimiter.
- Edit thanks to @tripleee - we need to strip the line breaks as it is a part of the string, thus `.index()` wouldn't find last columns. Then we add the `\n` back to the end of the line.

---

Input:

```
file1.txt

Number  N coordinates   E coordinates   Height  Code
1   5111945.980 444258.900  131.300 C
2   5265566.655 443665.554  110.311 BR
```

Output:

```
file2.txt

Number  E coordinates   N coordinates   Height  Code
1   444258.900  5111945.980 131.300 C
2   443665.554  5265566.655 110.311 BR
```

Comment: This doesn't cope with a data file where the last column needs to be moved. You should strip the line endings and then add them back, or simply use the `csv` library with tab delimiters.

Comment: @tripleee You're correct, I'll try and find a fix for it. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @tripleee Fixed :) thanks for the enlightenment, if you see more bugs I would gladly fix, or even delete the answer if necessary.

Comment: I see another issue - it adds a line break at the end, not sure if it is that ugly or important as it is being ignored anyways, I will wait for the OP's thoughts if it fulfils his intentions.

Comment: @no_hex Yup, works like a charm, that one :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so one way to accomplish it would be using the `pandas` library and the `StringIO` library (Notice that `pandas` is a library that you need to install with `pip install pandas`),

As you stated in the comments your txt file is a tab delimiter which means `\t` is what separates your columns, here is one way to accomplish that:

**Import libraries and load your file to a variable:**

```py
import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO

txt_path = dir_path + "/sample_txt_file.txt"
string = ""
with open(txt_path, 'r') as file:
    string = file.read()
```

With your dummy data the variable `string` will look like that:

```py
'Number\tN coordinates\tE coordinates\tHeight\tCode\n1 \t5111945.980\t444258.900\t131.300\tC\n2 \t5265566.655\t443665.554\t110.311\tBR'
```

**Read it as a dataframe:**

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep='\t')
```

**Reorder the column based on the columns you specify:**

```py
df = df[['Number', 'E coordinates', 'N coordinates', 'Height', 'Code']]
```

> Note, you can reorder as many of them as you want

**And save your data to a new txt file:**

```py
df.to_csv(new_txt_path, index=None, sep='\t')
```

**Resulting data will be like that:**

```py
Number  E coordinates   N coordinates   Height  Code
1       444258.900      5111945.980     131.300 C
2       443665.554      5265566.655     110.311 BR
```

Comment: You need to `pip install pandas` in order to use it, in an antithesis to the OP's comment: `"No external libraries, only default Python and it's libraries."`

Answer (score -1):

You can also utilize the power of the f-string formatting capability and do the following:

```
l = 0
for line in myfile:
    sl = [x for x in line.split(' ') if x]
    if l == 0:
        print(line) # prints first line without a swap
    else:
        print(f'{sl[0]:8}{sl[2]:16}{sl[1]:14}{sl[3]:10}{sl[4]:4}')
    l += 1
```

Comment: Meh, -1. 
1. The OP stated it is spaces by tabs.
2. It is not generic to the titles (what if a title is now to 16 characters long?