# Python - re-ordering columns in a csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a bunch of csv files with the same columns but in different order. We are trying to upload them with SQL*Plus but we need the columns with a fixed column arrange.

Example

required order: A B C D E F

csv file: A C D E B (sometimes a column is not in the csv because it is not available)

is it achievable with python? we are using Access+Macros to do it... but it is too time consuming

PS. Sorry if anyone get upset for my English skills.

Comment: Yes it is.  Use a regex pattern and away you go.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read, reorder, and then and write your file.

**Sample File:**

```
$ cat file.csv
A,B,C,D,E
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
```

**Code**

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    # output dict needs a list for new column ordering
    fieldnames = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    # reorder the header first
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        # writes the reordered rows to the new file
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**output**

```
$ cat reordered.csv
A,C,D,E,B
a1,c1,d1,e1,b1
a2,c2,d2,e2,b2
```

Comment: Really nice use of `DictReader`/`DictWriter`.

Comment: Beautiful solution. However, how can I make it work on input files that are delimited by a semicolon?

Comment: @user1192748 the docs for csv.reader [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader) define `delimiter=` and `quotechar=` kwargs to specify the delimiter and quoiting character.

Comment: Keep in mind that `DictWriter` for Python 2, doesn't support unicode characters as mentioned https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 12):

So one way to tackle this problem is to use `pandas` library which can be easily install using `pip`. Basically, you can download `csv` file to pandas dataframe then re-order the column and save it back to `csv` file. For example, if your `sample.csv` looks like below:

```
A,C,B,E,D                                                                                                                
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1                                                                                                           
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
```

Here is a snippet to solve the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/sample.csv')
df_reorder = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']] # rearrange column here
df_reorder.to_csv('/path/to/sample_reorder.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
csv_in  = open("<filename>.csv", "r")
csv_out = open("<filename>.csv", "w")

for line in csv_in:
    field_list = line.split(',')    # split the line at commas
    output_line = ','.join(field_list[0],   # rejoin with commas, new order
                           field_list[2],
                           field_list[3],
                           field_list[4],
                           field_list[1]
                           )
    csv_out.write(output_line)

csv_in.close()
csv_out.close()
```

Comment: What if there are quoted strings containing commas?

Comment: `output_line = ','.join(field_list[3],   # rejoin with commas, new order
TypeError: str.join() takes exactly one argument (4 given)`  when I was trying to use this with python3 (and a 4 column csv-file). Is this a pyhton2 script?

Comment: Yes, it's Python 2.7.  The switch to Python 3 was expensive in project terms, so most large organizations stayed with 2.7 as long as they could.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662656/how-to-reorder-the-columns-of-a-csv) to change the order, replacing ';' with ',' in your case.
Because you said you needed to do multiple .csv files, you could use the glob module for a list of your files

```
for file_name in glob.glob('<Insert-your-file-filter-here>*.csv'):
    #Do the work here
```

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module allows you to read csv files with their values associated to their column names. This in turn allows you to arbitrarily rearrange columns, without having to explicitly permute lists.

```
for row in csv.DictReader(open("foo.csv")):
  print row["b"], row["a"]

2 1
22 21
```

Given the file **foo.csv**:

```
a,b,d,e,f
1,2,3,4,5
21,22,23,24,25
```