# Re-ordering columns in a CSV file with a specified delimiter character

Tags: python, csv

Basically, I want to achieve exactly the same task that was solved in the approved answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001490/python-re-ordering-columns-in-a-csv).

However, this solution does not work for me in case the input CSV file uses semicolons as delimiters. I tried to change the code to be

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,  delimiter = ';')
```

but it does not do the trick and just results in a CSV with the new order, good header, but empty data (i.e., only the delimiters are written).

I am sorry to create a duplicate but given the age of the original post, I doubt that anyone would notice my question / comment over there.

I am using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os, csv

def reorder():
    with open('in.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'a') as outfile:
        fieldnames = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter = ';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
            writer.writerow(row)

def main():
    reorder()

# standard boilerplate to call the main() function to begin the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Given `in.csv` with the following content does not produce a good result:

```
A;B;C;D;E
a1;b1;c1;d1;e1
a2;b2;c2;d2;e2
```

Replacing the semicolon with commas produces a good result.

**Update:**

I changed the respective piece of code as follows, which works:

```
    with open('in.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], delimiter=';')

        fieldnames = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Can you post  sample data and expected output?

Comment: Since you're claiming this isn't a duplicate of the other question, please [edit] your question and add _all_ the code you're using, a sample of the input file, and the (incorrect) contents of the file it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what your DictReader is producing. You need to add `delimiter=';'` to the reader as well, not just the writer.