# Creating a function to read a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I need to write a function called `read_data` that reads the iris dataset. The columns are in this order:

```
Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
Column 4
Column 5
```

The columns need to be returned in the following order:

```
Column 1
Column 3
Column 2
Column 4
Column 5
```

I tried

```
def read(file_path):
    file_path = './file.csv'
    with open (file_path, 'r') as fin:
        for row in fin:
            print(row)
```

How to change the order of the columns?

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable. Also, `pandas` has some nice CSV utilities that may make your job easier

Comment: Python comes with a _built-in_ [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module, that should make it relatively easy to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the csv file to a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")

#Then you can rearrange the elements in the list how you want

df = df[['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3']]

df.to_csv("iris.csv")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There can be different approaches depending on what you want to do. [Here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001490/python-re-ordering-columns-in-a-csv) that shows how to switch columns when writing

Here is another 
really simple solution - it doesn't really on any other modules, but there may be easier solutions depending on what you are looking for.
Alter you function like this:

```py
for row in fin:
    cols = row.split(",")
    desired_order=[0,2,1,3,4]
    new_row = ""
    for num in desired_order:
        new_row += cols[num]
        new_row += ","
    print(new_row)
```

test input

```
1,2,3,4,5,
6,7,8,9,10
```

produces

```
1,3,2,4,5,
6,8,7,9,10,
```