# CSV file reformatting

Tags: python, csv, file, reformatting

I am new to python and am trying to reformat a CSV file, it is not delimited so all the data is in
the first column. The file is very large say 1 gb to big for excel.  The file format is as follows,
note the time sequence in the old file is reversed newest to oldest, want to reverse it in new file
with oldest to newest.

```
old file is
   tagname1 tagname2 value1(t)  value2(t) timestamp(t)
   tagname1 tagname2 value1(t-1)  value2(t-1) timestamp(t-1)
   tagname1 tagname2 value1(t-2)  value2(t-2) timestamp(t-2)

desired file format
   timestamp(t-2)    tagname1       tagname2   value1(t-2)    value2(t-2)
   timestamp(t-1)    tagname1       tagname2   value1(t-1)    value2(t-1)
   timestamp(t)      tagname1       tagname2   value1(t)    value2(t)
```

## Thanks

Comment: You are saying all data is in the first column, but the format you give has 5 columns?

Comment: Can you load the whole file into memory (it might need more than the file size)? This would make things easier ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk`. This command rearranges columns and sort by the first column and writes the result to `new.csv`

```
awk -F' ' '{print $5" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4}' OFS=, "old.csv" | sort > new.csv
```

For a python solution, you can use for rearranging columns [Python - re-ordering columns in a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001490/python-re-ordering-columns-in-a-csv) but sort having limited memory would be much simpler with `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use well-known `pandas` library to import and modify your `.csv` file. It is very popular and used very often. Here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=" ", header=None) # 1
data = data.iloc[::-1] # 2
data = data[[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]] # 3

data.to_csv("out.csv", sep=" ", header=None, index=None) # 4
```

1. Read `.csv` file.

   - Your file doesn't have any column names, so we pass `header=None`.
   - Use spaces as a separation character: `sep=" "`.
2. Reverse array, the last rows will be first.
3. Change the column order.
4. Export your data to another `.csv` file.

   - Specify separation char: `sep=" "`.
   - We don't want any special row indices or headers: `header=None, index=None`.